# Unable to reduce gap between Image and Border in Flutter

Tags: flutter, image, border, border-layout

I have a flutter code where I am trying to give details about a course. There is an image that I have below which I added a text. I have added a border around the image to make it look good.

For some reason there is extra gap between the image and the borders and I am unable to figure out why.

Adding the code that I have done below

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Image.asset(course.imagePath),
        Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, right: 15, left: 15),
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Text(
            course.title,
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
              fontSize: 18,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 200,
          child: GridView.count(
            crossAxisCount: 3,
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: const Color(0xFF38B6FF),
                    width: 2.0,
                  ),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Image.asset(
                      'Clock1.png',
                      height: 90,
                    ),
                    Text(course.time),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Image.asset(
                    'Items1.png',
                    height: 100,
                  ),
                  Text(course.Date)
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Image.asset(
                    'Picture1.png',
                    height: 100,
                  ),
                  Text(course.price)
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15, left: 15),
          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          child: Text(course.description),
        ),
```

And below is the image of what I am getting
[image]

Adding the image of the clock also to show that the image does not have any white spaces around that is making this happen
[image]

Please help me out in understanding why this is happening and how I can rectify it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra space is the result of the `Container` expands to the size of the given constraints from `GridView`. By default, the aspect ratio of a `GridView` child is `1.0`, which means the ratio of the width to the height is 1:1. You can experiment changing the value for the aspect ratio by using the `childAspectRatio` parameter of `GridView`:

```dart
GridView.count(
  childAspectRatio: 0.5,
  // ...
```

Now you can see that the space is even larger, with double the previous height.

To let your widget shrinks to the height it needed, wrap the `Container` with `Align` and set the `mainAxisSize` of the `Column` to `MainAxisSize.min`:

```dart
GridView.count(
  // ...
  children: [
    Align( // (1) Wrap the Container with Align
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter, // (2) Set the alignment to top-center
      child: Container(
        // ...
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, // (3) Set the main axis size to min
          // ...
        ),
      ),
    ),
    // ...
  ],
)
```

Comment: Thank you... Adding the Align and the setting the childaspectration to 1.4 worked.